# Есть ли библиотека для подсчета контрольной суммы modbus под android?

Tags: android-sdk, android, libmodbus, uart

Есть ли библиотека или мануал как подсчитывать контрольную сумму для протокола modbus под android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм рассчета CRC16 следующий:

1. В 16-битный регистр CRC загружаються единицы (0хFFFF);
2. Выполняется исключающее ИЛИ с первыми 8 битами байта сообщения и содержимым регистра CRC;
3. Результат сдвигается на один бит вправо;
4. Если сдвигаемый бит = 1, исключающее ИЛИ содержимого регистра со значением A001h;
5. Если сдвигаемый бит = 0, повторить шаг 3;
6. Повторять шаги 3, 4, 5, пока не будут выполнены 8 сдвигов;
7. Выполняется исключающее ИЛИ со следующими 8 битами байта сообщения и содержимым CRC регистра;
8. Шаги 3 – 7 повторять до тех пор, пока все байты сообщения не будут обработаны;
9. Конечное содержимое регистра CRC будет содержать контрольную сумму.

[Здесь](http://www.ammanu.edu.jo/wiki1/ru/articles/%D1%86/%D0%B8/%D0%BA/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4.html) есть хорошее описание всех вариантов рассчета контрольной суммы на языке С.

Реализация на языке C# выглядит так:

```
private static void myCRC(byte[] message, int length, out byte CRCHigh, out byte CRCLow)   {
   ushort CRCFull = 0xFFFF;
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
       CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull ^ message[i]);
       for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
       {
           if ((CRCFull & 0x0001) == 0)
               CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull >> 1);//(ushort)(CRCFull ^ 0xA001);
           else
           {
               CRCFull = (ushort)((CRCFull >> 1) ^ 0xA001);
           }
       }
   }
   CRCHigh = (byte)((CRCFull >> 8) & 0xFF);
   CRCLow = (byte)(CRCFull & 0xFF);
}
```

Чтобы вызвать в теле программы пишете:

```
byte[] data = new byte[8];
// Заполнение первых 6 байт информацией
byte High, Low;
myCRC(data, 6, out High, out Low);
data[6] = Low;
data[7] = High;
```